# Is it possible to set a port under "host mode" in docker?

Tags: docker

Is it possible to config the port number in docker under "host mode"?

I wanna bind the application to 5050 port instead of 80 port .

However, when I run below script, it will default bind in 80 port:

```
sudo docker run --name=myname --network host -d webapi:1.0.0 --restart=always
```

So I tried to run with "-p 5050", for example

```
sudo docker run --name=myname --network host -d webapi:1.0.0 --restart=always -p 5050
sudo docker run --name=myname --network host -d webapi:1.0.0 --restart=always -p 5050:5050
```

Unfortunately, my Linux terminal returned with :

```
WARNING: Published ports are discarded when using host network mode
```

The docker image looks like something like this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-2.2

And my Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /publish
COPY .  .
EXPOSE 5050
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApi.dll"]
```

Comment: Why you need this? Why can not delete `--net=host`?

Comment: thanks for your question. This is because there are a lot of things not hosting in docker, and the docker image cannot be isolated. Thus, the "network host mode" is the only choice.

Comment: I don't understand what prevents you to use -p to expose all you needed ports to host with `a lot of things not hosting in docker`. Anyway, `host net` will certainly can not map ports as it will just share the host's tcp-ip stack.

Comment: Just my thought, you can keep it to see if any other thoughts, good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks user "@atline" for the answer.
Only 80 port is allowed.
More reference is found here:
https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

Answer (score 1):

Easy way out would be to run your application on `5050` port. Once your container is up & running you must be able to access your app on port 5050 on Docker host. You need not to bind any kind of ports because you are using the host network itself.

Comment: yes, totally agree. unfortunately, it is restricted to use docker lol